# How to convert date format (whole column) and produce one more column with Quarter & Year

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, formatting, string-formatting

I have an excel file with a date column. Is there a way to change the date format to MM-DD-YY and create one more column with Quarter & Year? I am very new to Python and I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this one. Thanks!

**Current format**

Date format: Jan 1, 2016

**Desired outcome**

Date format: 01/01/2016

One more additional column with something like this "Q1-2016"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `datetime` module's got you covered. For input:

```
myDate = datetime.strptime(<datestring>, "%b %d, %Y")
```

And for output:

```
print(myDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Getting the quarter would be a little bit harder, but you could use `myDate.month` to figure something out with time ranges. See also, [python datetime reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

example, using simple division so january-march are Q1, april-june are Q2, etc.:

```
print("Q%d-%d" % (myDate.month // 3 + 1, myDate.year))
```